# Is there any way to make auto login?

Tags: users

I have a website which is built by code-igniter and drupal. i used drupal for community part. I would like to use only one login page instead of two(Drupal login & usual login). How can i modify the drupal login page. Once a user logged in never asked again when they go to drupal part(community). Is there any way to customize drupal login.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! _Is there any way to customize the login form?_ Yes, there is, but asking how to integrate CodeIgniter login into Drupal, or vice versa, is quite a broad question. If you are asking about a module, we don't suggest modules to use; if you are asking about code to write, we don't provide a _write code_ service; if you are asking about suggestions, we don't give suggestions, but answer questions with a definitive answer.